# CONCAT não funcionando

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
indicativo_ja_registrado,  
qra,
fez_contato, 
DATE_FORMAT(data_qso, '%d/%m/%y') AS data_qso, 
DATE_FORMAT(data_agora, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_agora,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data_qso, data_agora) AS Anos,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, data_qso + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data_qso, data_agora) YEAR , data_agora) AS Mes,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, data_qso + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, data_qso, data_agora) MONTH , data_agora) AS Dias,
    Anos,
    Mes,
    Dias,
    CONCAT(Anos, ' Anos ', Mes, ' Mes e ', Dias, ' Dias') AS Extenso        
    quantidade_dias, 
hora_qso, 
faixa_simplex_MHz, 
faixa_MHz_qso_trans_repetidora, 
faixa_MHz_qso_trans_outras, 
nome_pais  
FROM qry_pesquisa_dois 
ORDER BY qry_pesquisa_dois.data_qso DESC;
```

Os TIMESTAMPDIFF do 'Anos', 'Mes' e "Dias' tem resultado satisfatório, mas o CONCAT não funciona.

Comment: dá algum erro???

Comment: A resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de marcar o ✅ para aceitá-la. Assim poderá utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(Anos, ' Anos ', Mes, ' Mes e ', Dias, ' Dias') AS Extenso FROM (       
SELECT 
    indicativo_ja_registrado,  
    qra,
    fez_contato, 
    DATE_FORMAT(data_qso, '%d/%m/%y') AS data_qso, 
    DATE_FORMAT(data_agora, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_agora,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data_qso, data_agora) AS Anos,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, data_qso + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, data_qso, data_agora) YEAR , data_agora) AS Mes,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, data_qso + INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, data_qso, data_agora) MONTH , data_agora) AS Dias,    
    quantidade_dias, 
    hora_qso, 
    faixa_simplex_MHz, 
    faixa_MHz_qso_trans_repetidora, 
    faixa_MHz_qso_trans_outras, 
    nome_pais  
FROM qry_pesquisa_dois 
ORDER BY qry_pesquisa_dois.data_qso DESC ) t;
```

Comment: Virgilio,
dá algum erro???
Resp: Só não dava o resultado do CONCAT.
Sua sugestão funcionou corretamente.
Obrigado

Comment: Se a resposta te ajudou pode aceita como reposta da sua pergunta!